# Transitioning to a python monorepo - how to structure project with pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

I am currently transitioning multiple standalone Python projects into a single monorepo. Previously, each project was self-contained with its own `main` script, `Dockerfile`, and `setup.py` file for dependency management. Each project followed the `src` format, and we could directly import modules like so:

```
from foo import helper
```

As part of the migration, we are also modernizing our dependency management and build process. We've decided to use `pyproject.toml` and `poetry` instead of the traditional `setup.py`. A few things are not clear to us right now on how to structure our new monorepo in the right way.

### Should we have one `pyproject.toml` file for the whole project, or also one per each sub-package?

We've been experimenting with just one `pyproject.toml` file for the whole project, but then the import statement has been changed to:

```
from src.foo import helper
```

1. Is it possible to structure our monorepo such that we retain the old import structure (i.e., `from foo import helper`) while using a shared `pyproject.toml`?
2. If not, would it be advisable to maintain a separate `pyproject.toml` for each subpackage inside the monorepo?

### How should we organize our multiple Dockerfiles and main scripts in the monorepo?

Additionally, we are now faced with the challenge of generating multiple Dockerfiles, as each of our services requires its own Dockerfile and main script. Before the transition, each Dockerfile and main script was situated in the project's root directory. Tentatively, we have each `main` script in the project root directory, but there are a lot of them. We've avoided putting these in a separate directory since they still have to reference the `src` directory. This is how our project structure looks.

```
project/
+-- src/
+---- foo/
+---- bar/
+---- baz/
+---- ...
+-- tests/
+-- docker/
+---- foo.Dockerfile
+---- ...
+-- foo_main.py
+-- bar_main.py
+-- baz_main.py
+-- ...
+-- poetry.lock
+-- pyproject.toml
```

1. How should we organize our multiple Dockerfiles and main scripts in the monorepo? Is there a recommended directory structure or naming convention?

Lastly, what are the best practices or recommendations for structuring a Python monorepo that combines multiple projects and wants to use modern tools like poetry? Any insights or guidance would be deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have different projects, you should consider using git submodules

Comment: And if you're using git submodules, you should consider separating Dockerfile, unit tests, and other module specific stuff

Comment: You should have `pyproject.toml` file for each module, it will help you in the conditions, where you're working on single project at a time, and for whole as well, which will help you if you're doing any integration task